Is there any method to apply statistical mechanics to turbulence?
Since the phenomenon of turbulence can be regarded as a system far from equilibrium, I'm considering whether it is possible to describe a turbulent system using non-equilibrium statistical mechanics tools instead of dynamical and probability theory.
Furthermore, is it possible to describe some turbulent flow systems that are temporally stationary using equilibrium statistical mechanics tools?

As some keywords: Wave turbulence, Martin Siggia Rose DeDominicis Janssen action and (infrared) renormalization group. Arguably Zhakarov approach and most modern ones are statistical ones... Simple models such as Shell models are often just coupled langevin equation between modes. The typical problems are the same as the ones you see in fundamental statistical mechanics. For example, the typical closure problem which arises in the BBGKY hierarchy (in statistical mechanics) also arises in all statistical description of turbulence where you want to describe different statistical moment

Google Statistical Turbulence Theory.
